# Accessing the value in an input element

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Why does accessing the `innerHTML` of an `<input>` return blank, and what do I need to do in order to fix it?

This is a screenshot of my app:

[image: Screencast]

Full HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Scientific Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator">
    {{> calculator}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="console">
  <input id="console" type="text" value="0" />
</template>

<template name="buttons">
  <input type="button" value="7" class="button 7" />
  <input type="button" value="8" class="button 8" />
  <input type="button" value="9" class="button 9" />
  <input type="button" value="A" class="button A" />
  <input type="button" value="B" class="button B" />
  <input type="button" value="C" class="button C" />
  <input type="button" value="4" class="button 4" />
  <input type="button" value="5" class="button 5" />
  <input type="button" value="6" class="button 6" />
  <input type="button" value="A" class="button" />
  <input type="button" value="B" class="button" />
  <input type="button" value="C" class="button" />
  <input type="button" value="1" class="button 1" />
  <input type="button" value="2" class="button 2" />
  <input type="button" value="3" class="button 3" />
  <input type="button" value="A" class="button" />
  <input type="button" value="B" class="button" />
  <input type="button" value="C" class="button" />
  <input type="button" value="0" class="button 0" />
</template>

<template name="adminButtons">
</template>

<template name="calculator">
  <!-- make the interface for the Calculator -->
  {{>console}}
  {{>buttons}}
  {{>adminButtons}}
</template>
```

I am using Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `innerHTML` field is not used to get the values inside input elements; instead, you can use the `value` field.

So, for example, you would say

```
document.getElementById('console').value
```

to get the text inside the element with id `console`.

Comment: Thanks! What are those undefined lines for ?

Comment: The `<input>` element is an empty element (i.e. you created it in the HTML by saying `<input />`), so it doesn't have any HTML inside it.